# to ban sending html email from server

Tags: php, email

i am building up an email server. Is there any way that i can ban sending emails from my server in html format? Also if the user uses another smtp server like gmail to send email in html format but hosts the page on my site, is there any way that i can ban it? I just want to know whether its possible? I am using php for coding.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is fit for creating a front end for a webmailer.
If you can generally bann HTML mails depends on the mail server you use.

BUT:

**As long as any user input is processed by one of your scripts you can do it.**
If you implement skripts that use mail() or similar functions you can always send plain text mails and/or filter html text from the user input.
If your script uses another smtp server you can do filter the mail before you pass it on to the smtp server.